# NULL Pointer Exception Error Application Crashed After deleting multiple Item from Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on android Note application. And I want to delete multiple selected items at a time from RecyclerView as well as from SQLite database. For this I am using contextual action bar. But when I delete some items it shows the following error;

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.notes.Adapter$OnClickAction.onClickAction()' on a null object reference
        at com.notes.Adapter$1.onLongClick

How to solve this?

Adapter.java

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {

   private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public List<Note> notes, selected;
    OnClickAction receiver;
    public int id;
    public interface OnClickAction {
        void onClickAction();
    }
    Adapter(Context context, List<Note> notes){
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.notes = notes;
        this.selected=new ArrayList<>();
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.note_item,viewGroup,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

        final Note item = notes.get(i);

        String  title    = notes.get(i).getTitle();
        String  date     = notes.get(i).getDate();
        String  time     = notes.get(i).getTime();
        final long id       = notes.get(i).getId();
        Log.d("NC" ,"Date on: "+date);

        viewHolder.nTitle.setText(title);
        viewHolder.nDate.setText(date);
        viewHolder.nTime.setText(time);
        viewHolder.nID.setText(String.valueOf(notes.get(i).getId()));

        viewHolder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                if (selected.contains(item)) {
                    selected.remove(item);
                    unhighlightView(viewHolder);
                } else {
                    selected.add(item);
                    highlightView(viewHolder);
                }
                receiver.onClickAction();
                return true;
            }
        });

        if (selected.contains(item))
           highlightView(viewHolder);
        else
            unhighlightView(viewHolder);
    }
    private void highlightView(ViewHolder holder) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    }
    private void unhighlightView(ViewHolder holder) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return notes.size();
    }

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

      TextView nTitle,nDate,nTime,nID;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nTitle  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nTitle);
            nDate   = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nDate);
            nTime   = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nTime);
            nID     = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listId);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   // notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),NoteDetails.class);
                    i.putExtra("ID",notes.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
                    v.getContext().startActivity(i);
                    itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                }
            });
       }
    }
    public List<Note> getSelected() {

        return selected;
    }
    public void setActionModeReceiver(OnClickAction receiver) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    public void clearSelected() {
        selected.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Adapter.OnClickAction {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Adapter adapter;
    NoteDatabase noteDatabase;
    long id;
    ActionMode actionMode;

    private ActionMode.Callback actionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.delete_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.dlt:
                    delete();
                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            actionMode = null;
            adapter.clearSelected();
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        noteDatabase = new NoteDatabase(this);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listofnotes);

        FloatingActionButton button = findViewById(R.id.buttonadd);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Add New Note", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), AddNote.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    public void delete() {

        List<Note> newnote=adapter.getSelected();
       Log.d("NC","selected "+adapter.selected);

        for (int i=0; i<newnote.size(); i++){

            long id=newnote.get(i).getId();
            noteDatabase.deleteNote(id);
            Log.d("NC", "deleted: "+id);

            List<Note> getAllNotes = noteDatabase.getAllNotes();
            adapter=new Adapter(this,getAllNotes);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Note Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    private void displayList(List<Note> allNotes) {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new Adapter(this, allNotes);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.dltall) {
            noteDatabase.deleteAll();
            List<Note> notes = noteDatabase.getAllNotes();
            Log.d("NC", "Note after dlt " + notes);
            displayList(notes);
            Toast.makeText(this, "All Notes Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        List<Note> getAllNotes = noteDatabase.getAllNotes();
        if (getAllNotes.isEmpty()) {
        } else {
            displayList(getAllNotes);
            adapter.setActionModeReceiver((Adapter.OnClickAction)this);
        }
    }

    public void onClickAction() {
        int selected = adapter.getSelected().size();
        if (actionMode == null) {
            actionMode = startActionMode(actionModeCallback);
            actionMode.setTitle("Selected: " + selected);
        } else {
            if (selected == 0) {
                actionMode.finish();

            } else {
                actionMode.setTitle("Selected: " + selected);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what exception you received? indexoutofbound?? add crashlogs

Comment: @GaneshPokale  Error is in  receiver.onClickAction() in Adapter.java class. Error shows NullPointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to set the listner in delete()

```
 public void delete() {

        List<Note> newnote=adapter.getSelected();
       Log.d("NC","selected "+adapter.selected);

        for (int i=0; i<newnote.size(); i++){

            long id=newnote.get(i).getId();
            noteDatabase.deleteNote(id);
            Log.d("NC", "deleted: "+id);

            List<Note> getAllNotes = noteDatabase.getAllNotes();
            adapter=new Adapter(this,getAllNotes);
            adapter.setActionModeReceiver((Adapter.OnClickAction)this); // Add this
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Note Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```